# Confusion about Zabusky and Kruskal's stepper for the KdV equation

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics

In [Zabusky and Kruskal's](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.15.240) paper about solitons, they derive the following update for the Korteweg de Vries equation (their footnote 6):
\begin{align*}
u_{i}^{j+1} = u_{i}^{j-1}  - \frac{1}{3} \frac{k}{h} ( u_{i-1}^{j} + u_{i}^{j} + u_{i+1}^{j})(u_{i+1}^{j} - u_{i-1}^{j}) - \frac{\delta^2k}{h^3} (u_{i+2}^{j} -2u_{i+1}^{j} +2 u_{i-1}^{j} - u_{i-2}^{j})
\end{align*}
Their setup is an initial value problem (so that $u_{i}^{0}$ is known for all $i$) subject to periodic boundary conditions in $i$, so that $u_{i+2N}^{j} = u_{i}^{j}$. So I have no problem determining the $i$ indexes.

But if I only know $u_{i}^{0}$, then the update requires $u_{i}^{1}$ to get $u_{i}^{2}$. (Of course, once I know these, I can get going without problem.) So how can I use this scheme to get $u_{i}^{1}$?

(My current suspicion is that they used equation (6) $u = \cos(\pi(x-ut))$ for $u^1$. Still not sure.)

Comment: Didn't they use a ghost node for $u^{j - 1}$?

Comment: Another option is to use a high-accuracy single step explicit scheme to get $u^1$, then proceed using the multistep iteration. This is what is used in modern multistep integrators. Doing a single time step of RK4, for instance, would probably be more than accurate enough for your needs, and it also conserves momentum

Comment: @nicoguaro: I didn't see anything about a ghost node in their paper, though for my purpose it doesn't matter if I strictly follow exactly their procedure. You will have to forgive my ignorance, but I'm not familiar with how to populate the ghost nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\uu}{\mathbf{u}}$ The method can be condensed to
$$
\uu^{j+1}=\uu^{j-1}+2kF(\uu^j)
$$
which is the weakly stable 2-step Nyström scheme, also called "central Euler method". See [some remarks on the scalar method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3067889/115115) to see in the plot of the error profiles at the end that the method is rather sensitive on the choice of $\uu^1$. While the method is second order, an initialization of at least third order and sufficiently small time step is advisable. For simplicity, compute an RK4 step for $\dot \uu=F(\uu)$.

However, using the Nyström method or the lsoda solver, both methods produce a mountain scape that corresponds well with the Figure 2 in the paper.

[image: surface plot of the solution over time]

<sub>*$N=200$ sub-intervals in x-diretion, i.e., $h=0.01$. Using $k=0.05\frac{h^3}{\delta^2}$, with $\delta=0.022$from the paper*</sub>