# What's a nice simple PDE to play with in Matlab?

Tags: pde, matlab, numerical-modelling

I want to learn a very simple PDE to gain physical and mathematical intuition—a PDE with just one spatial dimension $x$ and a time dimension $t$. And, I want to write code for it in Matlab and use a standard PDE solver that Matlab might have, so that I can get a feel for the solution to the PDE and how the solution changes/behaves with a change in $x$ or $t$.

- I have no experience with PDEs.
- What could be a nice PDE to start with?
- What's a nice Matlab solver for PDEs?
- For ODEs, the Matlab solver ode45 is pretty nice to use.

Comment: A really basic one that fits your desired criteria could be the unsteady heat equation in 1D. As for PDE solvers in matlab, never used one so I can’t comment. I have always rolled my own PDE solving code if I write something in matlab.

Comment: @spektr interesting: is there a standard solver code that I could learn to write on my own?  do you have a reference maybe?  I'd also like to write a simple solver, so that I can understand the numerical method underlying the solver.

Comment: Well a common approach is to discretize the spatial derivatives of the PDE to obtain a system of ODEs and then solve this system with ‘ode45’ or something along these lines. The easiest discretization is to turn spatial derivatives into finite difference approximations.

Comment: @spektr how long does it take to learn this, in your estimation? maybe a week for the unsteady heat equation?  how many lines of matlab code would it be? less than 100 lines of code maybe?  (sorry for my cluelessness.)

Answer (score 5):

Standard examples of PDE to solve with the typically taught basic discretization methods (Crank-Nicolson et al.) are

- Transport equations, and other first order equations like Burger's, have often explicit solutions and conservation laws that the numerical methods more-or-less satisfy
- The heat equation with different boundary conditions and source terms is the teaching example for Crank-Nicolson and related methods,
- The KdV, Korteweg-deVries equation with a soliton wave ([animating a wave function in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59425195/3088138)) or multiples of them, ([Zabusky and Kruskal's stepper for the KdV equation](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/33414/6839)) is heavily non-linear and teaches why stiffness has to be taken into account, thus the use of implicit solver methods.
- In using complex-valued functions, one can explore the non-linear Schrödinger (NLS) equations ([pseudo-spectral method in NLS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29803342/3088138)), with the same difficulties as the last one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in modelling any type of PDE within MATLAB, the Partial Differential Equation Toolbox should be able to handle anything you're interested in.

- The [complete documentation for the toolbox can be found here.](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/pde/pde.pdf) .
- A suggested workflow for some simple examples can be found [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/solve-problems-using-pdemodel-objects.html).
- The solvable equations via the toolbox are described in detail [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/equations-you-can-solve.html).

This includes tools for meshing, solving and visualising the results from a user defined system of equations. It can handle both time and spatially dependent systems simultaneously.

The complete documentation holds a significant volume of worked examples which would probably be helpful in gaining some intuition for various systems. PDEPE make also be a useful function for 1D problems.